# setState works but the redux state isnt being updated when onClick is fired

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi so I was trying to update my redux state with a setState and for some reason it will only keep the original state and when I have an onClick fire off a setState it only updates that local state and it doesn't update the redux state and it just stay as the original state.

```
`class SubMenu extends Component {
  state={
    displayMenu: ''
  }
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.menuLayout(this.state.displayMenu)
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`${display}`}>
        Sub menu
         <ul>
          <li onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              displayMenu: 'd-none'
            })
          }}>
            Link1
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}`

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, { menuLayout})(SubMenu);`
```

and here is my action creator

```
`export const menuLayout = layout => {
    return {
        type: MENU_LAYOUT,
        payload: layout
    }
}`
```

and here is my reducer

```
`export default (state = "", action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MENU_LAYOUT":
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }
};`
```

Comment: All you do is call setState; no reason that'd automatically fire a redux action, which is how you change redux state.

Comment: You need to dispatch an action every time you want the redux store to update, not just on mount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your lifecycle events. It looks like you're trying to execute your flow with

```
componentDidMount()
```

The nature of this function is that it will only execute immediately after your component mounts and never again. So as it is right now, the onClick event that you have set up wouldn't do anything to update your redux state.

You need to setup an additional onChange event handler that will call your menuLayout action creator.

Comment: i put it in a componentDidUpdate and it solved the problem thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should be

```
export default (state = "", action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MENU_LAYOUT":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        displayMenu: action.payload
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
};`
```